# Javascript slideshow with innerHtml loop not working

Tags: javascript, loops, slideshow, innerhtml

I am trying to write a javascript code that will loop trough a list of array elements and write the in a loop inside a div, using innerHtml. I am looking for a pure javascript solution, no JQuery. I,m stuck.

Here is my relevant code and this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j3XD5/

```
<div id="slideshow">&nbsp;</div>
```

-

```
var url=new Array('im01.jpg', 'im02.jpg', 'im03.jpg', 'im04.jpg');
    var pause=2000;
    var p=0;
    function sl()
    {
    if (p<=url.length-1)
        {
        document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHtml = '<img name="pic" src='+url[p]+' border=0>';
        p++;
        var t=setTimeout(sl(),pause);
        }
        else
        {
        p=0;sl()
        }

    }

    window.onload=sl();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `sl` function instead of passing it as value.

Change

```
var t=setTimeout(sl(),pause);
```

to

```
var t=setTimeout(sl,pause);
```

and

```
window.onload=sl();
```

to

```
window.onload=sl;
```

As JavaScript is case sensitive, you must also change `innerHtml` to `innerHTML`.

You can also make the whole much simpler by using `%` instead of a test.

Here's a working code (style fixed according to [usual guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml), too) :

```
var pause=1000, p=0;
window.onload = function sl(){
    document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHTML = '<img name="pic" src="'+url[p]+'" border=0>';
    p = (p+1)%url.length;
    setTimeout(sl, pause);
};
```

**<kbd>[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/evuqiz/2/)</kbd>**